# Executing Ant to compile jars in command prompt errors

Tags: ant, jar, command-prompt

Hi I just picked up Programming (Java) a few months ago. I am having some problems to compile Jars files using Ant on command prompt. I do not have Ant installed but I do have a copy of Ant in another folder. So how can I execute this "ant jar" command in command prompt in the specified directory?

```
Directory to run "ant jar": C:\Program Files\GATE_Developer_7.1\plugins\MultiPaX\
Directory containing a copy of Ant: C:\Program Files\GATE_Developer_7.1\lib
```

Is it possible to do this without installing Ant? Thank you.

EDIT: 
I have downloaded and unzipped Ant into C:\ant. Then, I set the path as given below. But it's giving me some errors.

Build Failed
C:\Program Files...\MultiPaX\classes creation was not successful for an unknown reason.

Comment: Why don't you want to install ant?

Comment: @tieTYT - Actually I have installed Ant but I am getting some errors. I thought maybe I didn't install it properly so I was trying to use the Ant copy that came with GATE.

Comment: In recent GATE versions we no longer include a complete copy of ant in the distribution. There are still a couple of ant-related jar files in lib because they are needed as compile-time dependencies (GATE includes a couple of ant tasks) but you need to install a separate copy of the full ant distribution to be able to actually build things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem previously and this is what I tried...

1) Download Ant.

2) Unzip it and place it wherever you want: in this case C:\ant.

3) Open a command prompt and enter those commands:

```
C:\>set ANT_HOME=C:\ant
C:\>set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25
C:\>set PATH=%PATH%;%ANT_HOME%\bin
```

4)  To ensure your Ant is installed correctly type this into the command prompt:

```
C:\>ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.1 compiled on May 15 2013
```

If you receive this message, then your Ant is probably installed correctly.

5) Navigate to the directory you want to compile your file and type in "ant jar" in command prompt.

If this still does not work, you might want to make sure that you checked folder's permission for the directory where Ant is supposed to compile the files.

```
Changing folder permissions:
1) Right click on the folder > Properties > Security.
2) Click on Edit or Advanced to change the permission.
```

To read more on how to do this check out the answers from MS website:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/how-do-i-change-folder-and-file-permissions/465f2b42-63dd-4486-8dd1-c870290efeed

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set ANT_HOME environment variable that point to the Ant folder you want. After that, you can call Ant from everywhere in the comman prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can set ANT_HOME as suggested above and then set PATH variable to take you to bin folder of it like as below:

ANT_HOME=C:\ant
PATH=%PATH%; %ANT_HOME%\bin; //Given bin folder is under C:\ant else take ANT_HOME to one level above bin folder of ant.

After this you can ant command from any place in command prompt.

Hope this will help.